# MailMerge with OpenXML

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I have a sharepoint hosted application which contains a docx template file which has mailmerge fields like << Customer_Name >>.
It is a 1 Page document. I have to create a new docx file from this template which might contain multiple pages depending upon the number of customer. The content will be repeated and the merge fields has to be replaced with data from datatable for each page.

I tried using **AltChunk** but after using this method i cannot find and replace the text fields.

```
     using (WordprocessingDocument template = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentStream, true))
                        {
                            template.ChangeDocumentType(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
                    MainDocumentPart mainPart = template.MainDocumentPart;
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() != "")
                        {
                            ReplaceText(mainPart, "«customer_Address»", dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());   

        string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Substring(0, 15);
                                    AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);   

                                    chunk.FeedData(filestream); 
                                    AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
                                     altChunk.Id = altChunkId;  

                                     mainPart.Document
                                                     .Body
                                                     .InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().Last());
       mainPart.Document.Save();
}
}
```

I am using ReplaceText Method to Replace text from paragraph.

```
private static void ReplaceText(MainDocumentPart docPart, string match, string value)
        {
            var body = docPart.Document.Body;

            foreach (var text in body.Descendants<Text>())
            {
                if (text.Text.Contains(match))
                {
                    text.Text = text.Text.Replace(match, value);
                }
            }
        }
```

This ReplaceText works fine for origional mainPart but does nothing for text added using AltChunk.
What would be easier way to generate multi page document in my case?

Comment: _I want a [packet of Tim Tams that never runs out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoggSVxghWs)_ . Welcome to SO. Please don't post requirements and like Tim Tims, expect code to magically appear. Any code to show? What research have you done? Good luck!